# Print inputs in back wards. take Input from Command Line and its not printing backward

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i=0;
    for (i=1; i<argc;i++){
```

Counting string length.

```
        int l = strlen(argv[i]);

        int a=1;
        int start = 0;
        int end = l-1;
```

I think i have problem in looping.

```
        for (a=start;a>=end;a--)
            printf ("%c",argv[a][i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
for (a=end;a>=start;a--)
    printf ("%c",argv[i][a]);
```

Your code had `start` and `end` swapped and also `a` and `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Example answer below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i;
for (i = argc-1; i >0; i--)
printf("%s%s", argv[i], (i < argc-1) ? " " : "");
return 0;
}
```

// there is no need for extra variables - just one but the for loop starts from max argc and end ends when zero is reached (nearly)

Comment: That is not backwards. I thought that was what the question wanted.